# Laravel Admin dashboard

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having a Laravel project with an admin side.
I want the admin to have access to registered users.
I'm having a route called users on the admin dashboard. When that route is clicked I want to display all registered users.

Any help please..

Comment: Can you show us what you already tried?

Comment: StackOverflow is not for tutorials, go and search on google or youtube some tutorials, and if you have any specific error or problem, come back here and feel free to ask

Answer (score -1):

first, make a controller.
example: - `UsersController`
code: -

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use DB;
class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    public function index()
    {   
        $all_users = DB::table('users');
        $all_users = $all_users->get();
        return view('home')->with(['all_users'  => $all_users]);
    }
}
```

The route would be like: -

```
Route::get('home', 'UsersController@index');
```

The Home view page would be like: -

```
    <table class="table table-info table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr class="table-primary">
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>User Created At</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @foreach ($all_users as $users)
            <tr>
          
            <td>{{ $id_loop++ }}</td>
          <td>{{ $users->name }}</td>
          <td>{{ $users->email }}</td>
          <td>{{ $users->username }}</td>
          <td>
           @if(Cache::has('user-is-online-' . $users->id))
             <span class="text-success"><b>Online</b></span>
           @else
             <span class="text-secondary"><b>Offline</b></span>
           @endif
          </td>
          <td>{{ $users->created_at }}</td>
         </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
  </table>
```